# How do I get my web site to recognize a COM reference that may not exist on the server

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am creating an Excel spreadsheet from my web site.  I have added a reference to the site through the properties page that points to the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe on my local drive.  Everything works fine running locally.  However, when I publish to the server where the site runs, I get an error because it can't see the Excel.exe file.  Where does this file need to be in order for the site to see it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because your application is running as another login on the server as opposed to locally on your box.  Investigate what user the application's app pool runs as, then ensure that user has read/execute access to the location on the server where the Excel.exe file is.